# Should centered background respect paddings

Tags: css, webkit, background-image

[Here is](http://dabblet.com/gist/1620842) a snippet (if you are using Opera, check out [this](http://dabblet.com/result/gist/1620842) link).
As we can see In webkit browser we can see that background image respects padding while centering,
and in (at least Firefox and Opera) things go different.

[image: here it is webkit]
[image: non-webkit]

So, the question is following - what behaviour is actually correct, and, far far more important, how can I unify layout?

**UPD:** don't waste your time trying to find appropriate rule in notorious css reset sets, since I've already tried )))

Comment: First of all do you use a css reset? A common one is Eric Meyer's. http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css

Comment: By applying a css reset you will have a unified layout to work with

Comment: I am not answering , I am asking in order to verify that you use a css reset...

Comment: @chchrist - deleted comment, will edit the question to makes thing clearer.

Comment: off the topic, love your design page!

Comment: can't see anything in your snippet (am using opera)

Comment: @Nacho, my bad, dabblet uses CORS, that's the reason it won't work in currunt Opera, so, here is link for Opera -  http://dabblet.com/result/gist/1620842 - will fix question. Thank you!

Comment: Well that's an interpretation of table cells problem. Each navigator actually treats it differently... have you tried other doctype rather than `<!DOCTYPE html>`, like `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're problem isn't the `background-origin` it's the `box-sizing`.

Looks like webkit's box-sizing is `content-box` and mozilla's is `border-box` making webkit's cell-height 242px (height + padding + border) and mozilla's 200px. And since your vertical background position is centered, it's creating extra vertical space. Simply set **`box-sizing:border-box`** for consistency between the two modern browsers.

<strike>Here's a new one: http://dabblet.com/gist/1621656</strike>

**EDIT:**
While the above fixes Chrome (webkit), it does not seem to fix Safari 5.1 (webkit). It appears that each browser has a buggy implementations of the box-sizing property for table-cells. In fact, if you even look at the Notes section of the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/box-sizing) it says `box-sizing` isn't even applied in Mozilla.

Therefore, we must solve your height issue a different way. Good news, according to the [CSS2.1 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#height-layout) we should be able to define the height we want from the `TR`. Here's a new that works in my Safari, Chrome and Firefox versions: http://dabblet.com/gist/1622122

Comment: thank you for this answer, but are you sure. border-box was first thing I've tried, to be honest.  In my browsers (Safari/Firefox) there is exactly the same issue, yet unresolved. There IS a gap in webkit, and there is NOT - in non-webkit browsers.

Comment: Hmm.. you're right, Safari was broken (Chrome was fine, though). Even so, it is the height (via box-sizing) that is your problem (you can see in your screenshot how webkit's cells are taller b/c of the padding). The solution w/o using box-sizing is to set the height in the table row, rather than the cells. I've edited my answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: @rghtree, that's something. Me also came up to conclusion that the reason is just that box-siing is just not fully implemented. I guess this is the closest I could get. Thanks a lot.